# How do I define JOIN precedence in SqlKata

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlkata

I'm using SqlKata in my project and it's necessary to connect several tables with the help of nested join. I expect to see something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (t2 LEFT JOIN t3 ON t3.id = t2.id) 
ON t2.id = t1.id
```

In Join/LeftJoin/RigthJoin methods, I did not find any overloads that would accept anything other than a join or other request.

Wouldn't want to manually make such connections, maybe someone has already faced such a problem? That would be great, I would really appreciate a hint.

Comment: Which connections are you talking about? How it differs from general SqlKata approach?

Comment: What have you tried I don't see anything complex in this query?

Comment: The query is really not difficult. I'm talking about this part of JOIN: LEFT JOIN (**[dbo].[Table1] t2 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table2] t3 ON t3.ObjectID=t2.P683** ) ON t2.ObjectID=t1.P4296. That is, attach a third table to the attached table. QueryBuilder probably does not allow to make a JOIN inside a JOIN. Or, anyway, I didn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining JOIN precedence is not available in SqlKata at the moment.

But you can achieve same result by using a Sub Query.

```
var query = new Query("t1")
    .LeftJoin(
        new Query("t2").LeftJoin("t3", "t3.id", "t2.id").As("tmp"),
       j => j.On( "tmp.id", "t1.id")
    );
```

This query would result in the following sql:

```
SELECT * FROM [t1] LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM [t2] LEFT JOIN [t3] ON [t3].[id] = [t2].[id]
) AS [tmp] ON ([tmp].[id] = [t1].[id])
```